# Using regex/search to find a string and isolate the column

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

Hi so what I am trying to achieve is to locate the column in my csv file (converted to a dataframe) that contains the word 'outbound' and isolate that column, and the two columns next to it. So far I have tried the following snippets of code to no avail.

```
    mask = np.column_stack([NB_2c17_newburden[col].str.contains(r"outbound", na=False) for col in NB_2c17_newburden])
```

as well as using search

```
    for line in NB_2c17_newburden:
       if re.search('outbound', line):
         print (line)
```

I was just using print line to see if it would work. Any help would be appreciated.

In R it has been achieved with the following code:

```
  i <- grep('outbound',NB_2c17_newburden)
  i <- i:(i+2)
```

But I am not sure how to convert that to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"col1":["one","two","three"],"col2":["four","five","six"],"col3":["seven","outbound","nine"],"col4":["ten","eleven","twelve"]})

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if pd.Series.any(df.iloc[:,i].str.contains(pat="outbound")):
        new_list=pd.DataFrame({df.columns[i-1]:df.iloc[:,i-1],df.columns[i]:df.iloc[:,i],df.columns[i+1]:df.iloc[:,i+1]})

print(new_list)

  col2      col3    col4
0  four     seven     ten
1  five  outbound  eleven
2   six      nine  twelve
```

Comment: Thank you!! Perfect